# customize-cra Minify and Embbeed CSS into HTML

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am working on a React project. I want my CSS to be embedded into HTML itself without having a network call for CSS.

CSS

```css
body{
   background-color: #000000;
}
```

into one file like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <style>
    body{
      background-color: #000000;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have no knowledge of webpack
I have setup `customize-cra` and have `config-override.js` file.

```js
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  // do stuff with the webpack config...
  return config;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

May be this is what you need ["react-style-tag"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-style-tag)

From your post I think you want to have your styles inside the  of your index.html file